# How to secure secret keys in Android App?

Tags: android, security, authentication, backend, secret-key

My Android App has an excel export and import feature, which I recently wanted to secure by adding a write-protection key. At first I put the key hardcoded in the source code, but obviously this is not secure at all because of reverse engineering.
I read a lot and I think my solution is now secure, but I am not sure. Could you maybe have a look  and point out possible caveats?

1. Users who want to export the excel must sign in using their Google Account with Google Sign in.
2. My app requests a sign in token from google (verified by sha signature)
3. Sign in token is sent to my server (HTTPS POST)
4. My server verifies that the token is a valid one verified by Google.
   Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth
5. Send back App account infos and excel export secret as JSON format (HTTPS POST)
6. App protects excel sheet with password and exports it.

Only excel sheets, which were exported with the supplied password can be imported again.

I also have a PDF export feature. The PDF should be signed by the app. The procedure is the same as before, but with a pkcs key containing the private and public key as base64 string.

How about rooted devices, could a attacker then maybe get the sent password/pkcs key?

Comment: The files to be exported are are stored in the mobile device or they are retrieved from the backend server each time they are needed? The imported files will be stored permanently in the mobile device or sent to the backend server?

Comment: The files to be exported are generated on the device but the key for write protection is not. The key is requested each time with token and sent back only when requested by Google user and restricted to my app signature (by Google api Google sign in process with backend server nodejs module)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### POSSIBLE CAVEATS

> I read a lot and I think my solution is now secure, but I am not sure. Could you maybe have a look and point out possible caveats?

**In a first glance:**

1. From the moment a private key leaves your backend server it belongs to the public domain, therefore it MUST be considered compromised.
2. The mobile app is making important decisions, signing documents and verifying their signature, and this can be bypassed at run-time with instrumentation frameworks, like Frida and xPosed.
3. The backend server is only authenticating the user in the request, but not **what** it's making the request.

#### 1. Private Key

> 5. Send back App account infos and excel export secret as JSON format (HTTPS POST)
>
> The procedure is the same as before, but with a pkcs key containing the private and public key as base64 string.

The only way a *private key* can be kept private it's to have it securely stored where it's meant to be used, and I strongly recommend to generate it in the same place it's being used, aka the same server.

From the moment the *private key* leaves the backend server, it's not anymore securely stored, and it's now up for grabs by anyone with the skills and knowlodge to use the plethora of open source and paid tools for reverse engineering static binaries or even to introspect them during run-time, and change their behaviour or extract data, aka your *private key*.

For static binary analysis we have an open source tool [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF), that combines under the hood several other open source tools, that de-compiles, analyses and extracts data from a static binary.

**MobSF**

> Mobile Security Framework (MobSF) is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing, malware analysis and security assessment framework capable of performing static and dynamic analysis. MobSF support mobile app binaries (APK, IPA & APPX) along with zipped source code and provides REST APIs for seamless integration with your CI/CD or DevSecOps pipeline.The Dynamic Analyzer helps you to perform runtime security assessment and interactive instrumented testing.

Regarding run-time, one can use [Frida](https://frida.re/) or [xPosed](https://www.xda-developers.com/xposed-framework-hub/) to hook into the place of the code where the *private key* is used and extract it to the attacker server.

**Frida**

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

**xPosed**

> Xposed is a framework that allows users to easily apply add-ons (called Modules) to the ROM. Rather than flashing a new ROM to get a specific feature, you can use Xposed to add individual features to whatever ROM you’re using, or even just the stock ROM.

#### 2. In App Decisions

> 6. App protects excel sheet with password and exports it.
>
> Only excel sheets, which were exported with the supplied password can be imported again.

As I already mentioned before in this answer, Frida and XPosed can be used to introspect and instrument code during run-time.

The attacker can use one of this tools to just hook in the function that says if the document is correctly signed, and return always `true`, thus bypassing all the intended security mechanisms shipped in the code of the mobile app. This is an alternative approach of the previous one I mentioned of using Frida or xPosed to extract the private key during run-time.

#### 3. Who vs What is accessing the backend server

> 1. Users who want to export the excel must sign in using their Google Account with Google Sign in.
> 2. My app requests a sign in token from google (verified by sha signature)
> 3. Sign in token is sent to my server (HTTPS POST)
> 4. My server verifies that the token is a valid one verified by Google. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

This 4 steps only identify **Who** is in the request, by other words, the user the request was made for, but doesn't provide any form of identifying **What** made the request in the behalf of the user.

For a more in depth explanation I recommend you to read an article I wrote, specifically the section: [Do You Know The Difference Between Who And What Is Communicating With Your Api Server?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what):

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.
>
> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

You may be surprised how often the attacker is your genuine user trying to bypass your system.

### POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS

#### Caveat 1

To address caveat 1 you must keep the private key at all times in your backend server, and **NEVER** sent it in any response to the mobile app.

#### Caveat 2

The caveat 2 can be addressed by not signing or verifying the document in the mobile app, instead you do it in your backend server, and you must be sure that your backend server knows **Who** and **What** it's making the request.

#### Caveat 3

The caveat 3 it's already partially solved, once you already know **Who** it's in the request, you just need to implement a robust solution to know **What** it's making that request on the user behalf.

The most common way to identify **What** it's making the request to the backend server, it's the use of a secret in the header of the request, that you may know as `APi-Key`, `Access-Token` or whatever other name was chosen, but you can see how this approach it's easily bypassed with a Man in the Middle(MitM) attack in the article [Steal That Api Key With A Man In The Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

A more robust solution can be used, where a another server attests the mobile app integrity, that will allow the backend server to know when to trust in **What** is making the request, and this concept is known by Mobile App Attestation.

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is explained in more detail in an article I wrote, at the section [The Role of Mobile App Attestation](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-protect-against-certificate-pinning-bypassing#mobile-app-attestation):

> The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to authenticate **what** is sending the requests, thus only responding to requests coming from genuine mobile app instances and rejecting all other requests from unauthorized sources.
>
> In order to know **what** is sending the requests to the API server, a Mobile App Attestation service, at run-time, will identify with high confidence that your mobile app is present, has not been tampered/repackaged, is not running in a rooted device, has not been hooked into by an instrumentation framework(Frida, xPosed, Cydia, etc.), and is not the object of a Man in the Middle Attack (MitM). This is achieved by running an SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device it is running on.
>
> On a successful attestation of the mobile app integrity, a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud know. In the case that attestation fails the JWT token is signed with an incorrect secret. Since the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, it is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the app has been tampered with, is running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is the target of a MitM attack.
>
> The mobile app must send the JWT token in the header of every API request. This allows the API server to only serve requests when it can verify that the JWT token was signed with the shared secret and that it has not expired. All other requests will be refused. In other words a valid JWT token tells the API server that what is making the request is the genuine mobile app uploaded to the Google or Apple store, while an invalid or missing JWT token means that what is making the request is not authorized to do so, because it may be a bot, a repackaged app or an attacker making a MitM attack.

While not easy to build your own Mobile App Attestation service, it's feasible to do by a knowledgeable team of engineers, and the main thing to keep in mind it's that the SDK doesn't perform any decisions, just responds to the random challenges given by the server, that it's the one responsible to make the decision of the integrity of the mobile app.

### CONCLUSION

Your current defenses are better than your initial one's, and you have room for improvements, and how much effort you should put in increasing the security of your mobile app and backend server may need to be balanced against the laws regulating what you are doing, the knowlodge and resources available to you and your team, and proportional to the value of what you are protecting.

As i final note I strongly suggest that you address caveat 1 and 2, and give a try to caveat 3.

### GOING THE EXTRA MILE

I allways like to recommend this very valuable resource [OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg)

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

Comment: The Google Sign in API is already attesting that the request is really from my app. I restricted the successful token response at the Google cloud console to the SHA1 signature of my app and there is documentation that a malicious app would not pass this check on my backend server.

Comment: Great answer, by the way! Thank you very much, I did not know how much was possible at runtime... As a single developer who programs in his free time while being a teacher my resources are somewhat limited. The app is for one man businesses who want to manage travel expenses and other tax relevant income or expenses in the app. The protection is there so that the user cannot edit the data after some time unless it is documented why and when. This is a requirement by law. Okay- I will not send the private key. Do you maybe know resources on how to sign a PDF visually with node?

Comment: An attacker can use an instrumentation Framework during runtime to always send the correct SHA1 signature expected by Google, therefore being able to spoof and manipulate the requests and behavior of your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there no 100% secure way to store it, even if you compile it into a native C file.

To hide them you can encrypt it and decrypt it a the execution time. To encrypt you strings and inject fake code to lost hackers, you can try this Gradle plugin: https://github.com/christopherney/Enigma

I wrote a short article on it: https://medium.com/@christopherney/protect-android-app-against-reverse-engineering-with-enigma-string-obfuscation-plugin-11687022cbef

There is others plugin such as https://github.com/StringCare/AndroidLibrary

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I don't store the key on the device, I send it over HTTPS after successful authentication and use it only in memory.

Comment: @FloJ12 - There is still no solution.  All the bad guys need to do is to execute your app on a platform that they can attach a debugger to.